# JQuery cloud carousel is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement cloud carousel which should start cycling as soon as the page loads and pauses when hovered upon.But I am not able to do anything with my code.

I am doing it for the first time, so I cannot figure out the error. I have included the libraries but it's still giving me this error.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cloud-carousel").CloudCarousel({
    xPos:285,
    yPos:120,
    speed:0.15,
    xRadius: 16,
    yRadius: 170,
    autorotate:'left',
    buttonLeft: $("#left-but"),
    buttonRight: $("#right-but"),
    mouseWheel:true
  })
})
```

```css
img{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  }
```

```html
   <head>
   

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="cloud-carousel.1.0.5.js"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.min.js">
    </script>
      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="cloud-carousel" class="carousel cloud-carousel active" style="postion:relative; overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="carousel-cycle" style="display-block">
    <a class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/1458289957powerful-images3.jpg" class="carousel cloudcarousel "/>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdC9d6Z2Al0vMxQRqFc0230CUo-C-1BhIC3I5R9XTFw7MQLdeP" class="carousel cloudcarousel" />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRaKH4dU_U6Pe6WX5G8B9DZkkpzGHUxUJeGmOHbwKh6KrFsZsm6" class="carousel cloudcarousel" />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRaKH4dU_U6Pe6WX5G8B9DZkkpzGHUxUJeGmOHbwKh6KrFsZsm6" class="carousel cloudcarousel"/>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdC9d6Z2Al0vMxQRqFc0230CUo-C-1BhIC3I5R9XTFw7MQLdeP" class="carousel cloudcarousel"/>
<a>
  </div>
  
  </div>
        <input id="left-but"  type="button" value="Left">
        <input id="right-but" type="button" value="Right">
</body>
```

Comment: what error comes up exactly? and can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: If you run the code snippet above, this error comes ----- {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).CloudCarousel is not a function",
  "filename": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js",
  "lineno": 2,
  "colno": 31851
},                                                                                                                                 I am getting the same error @Gabbax0r

Comment: that error is coming because of this: `<script src="cloud-carousel.1.0.5.js"></script>` SO don't host cloud-carousel. You need to provide complete CDN path of it.

Comment: what do you mean? Please elaborate @vijayP

Comment: he means that this is not a valid path to your source. if you want to load it locally provide the full or relativ path or include it via cdn, like cloudfare or bootstrap

Comment: okay @Gabbax0r, I was looking for libraries but couldn't find one for this.Do you know the path for it?

Comment: do you have the js file in one of your folders? or in the same folder like your html?

Comment: @aayushi - you may download it from :  http://www.isgoodstuff.com/wp-content/demo/CarouselHTML5/cloud-carousel.1.0.5.min.js

Comment: actually I am using codepen to do the code. Link https://codepen.io/asinha/pen/vmVRZa @Gabbax0r

Comment: if i include that in my code, everything goes away @vijayP here is my codepen link https://codepen.io/asinha/pen/vmVRZa . Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

See my code below this might help you...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myCarousel_15').hover(function(){
   $("#myCarousel_15").carousel('pause');
  },function(){
   $("#myCarousel_15").carousel('cycle');
  });
 });
```

```css
.adjust-img
{
 width : 100%;
 height : 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
 <div id="myCarousel_15" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#myCarousel_15" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel_15" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel_15" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
  </ol>
  
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div class="item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull.jpeg" alt="Title goes here.">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h3>Title goes here.</h3>
     <p>This is 1st image of iceland and this is its caption</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.icelandprocruises.co.uk/media/img/gallery/home/0002-gallery-iceland-waterfall-1.jpg" alt="Title goes here.">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h3>Title goes here.</h3>
     <p>This is 2nd image of iceland and this is its caption</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item active">
    <img src="http://querzy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/iceland.jpg" alt="Title goes here.">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h3>Title goes here.</h3>
     <p>This is 3rd image of iceland and this is its caption</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel_15" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel_15" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span> 
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't to make slides. I saw this code on bootstrap. I wanted it like cloud-carousel only. Thanks anyway ! :)